# What techniques exist for clustering road routes?

Tags: intersection, routing, clustering, parallel-lines

The typical clustering (by proximity) techniques that I've seen - hotspots or marker counts - relate to single point data. Different challenges exist for deciding the significance of proximity in multi point line_strings e.g. road routes:

- many routes may start together but finish separately
- only a single intersection is shared vs. parallel routes

What techniques exist for grouping a number of lines?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and edit your question to include what GIS software you are using and what you have tried already/why those results were not as expected.  Also, if you could give a little clarification on what your desired end result is, it would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you mean Map Matching? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching